# HikariCp metrics collection using micrometer in Java springboot application by configuring it in

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, hikaricp, spring-micrometer

community,
I have a requirement where I want to do HikariCp metrics collection using micrometre in Java spring boot application by configuring it. I was looking around but I could not find much help in the official documentation

> https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/tree/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari

Can anyone please help me with how to do that?
Note: In the official documentation of Hikari they have provided a way to set metric registry for dropwizard but I wanted to do it with Micrometre.

Comment: When Spring Boot Actuator is on the classpath those are exported automatically.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, I do not see it inside /metrics names array. It has JVM and tomcat metrics but not Hikari Cp.

Comment: There are datasource metrics exposed, if not make sure you enable them (but afaik they are automatically added).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only data source autoconfigured is exposed for metrics in my case I have a custom Hikari data source configuration.

```
public myDataSource(){
   DataSource datasource = this.createDataSource();// you can write your own implementation to create datasource. you can pass URL, username etc to create it.
 this.setUpHikariWithMetrics();
}

public void setUpHikariWithMetrics() {
    if (dataSource instanceof HikariDataSource) {
        ((HikariDataSource) dataSource).setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
    }
}
```