# Spring boot, prometheus and hikaricp

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, multi-tenant, hikaricp, micrometer

How to export HikariCP metrics to prometheus, considering an application with multiple datasources (multitenant) and using micrometer?

I did not find any tips on how to do this on docs.

I was able only to export metrics from one datasource, the main datasource.

application.yml

```yaml
# actuator
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,info,metrics,prometheus
  # prometheus
  management:
    metrics:
      enable:
        jvm: true
      export:
        prometheus:
          enabled: true
      distribution:
        sla:
          http:
            server:
              requests: 50ms,100ms,200ms,300ms,500ms,1s
      tags:
        application: my-app
```

prometheus.yml

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s

scrape_configs:

- job_name: prometheus
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - prometheus:9090

- job_name: my-app
  metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - my-app:8080
```

Relevant Datasource Bean (multitenant application, multiple datasources - or hikari pools)

```java
    private final Map<Object, Object> dataSources = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    //...data sources initialization

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSourceRouter()
    {
        final var tenantDataSourceRouter = new MultitenantDataSourceRouter();
        tenantDataSourceRouter.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);

        final var dataSourcePadrao = dataSources.get("main-datasource");
        tenantDataSourceRouter.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSourcePadrao);

        return tenantDataSourceRouter;
    }
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72866503/21363224), but for two datasources?

Comment: metricRegistry comes from where? what class is metricRegistry?

Comment: I have found it, it is from io.micrometer.core, after adding this, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the `meterRegistry` to the `HikariConfig` like this:

```java
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
[...]
  /**
   * Prometheus app's set of meters
  */
  @Autowired
  private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
[...]
  public DataSource createHikariDataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(properties);
    [...]
    // Add prometheus metric registry
    config.setMetricRegistry(meterRegistry);
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
  }
```

That's just an example depending of your Hikari usage, but I think it may help you to get the idea.